# Angular App Crashes Without an Error As to Why

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, runtime-error, ngrx

The angular app i work on used to run on version 8, i upgraded it to version 17 along side all the company apps, one of them is crashing instantly as soon as the homepage loads in, it is no longer responsive, neither are the devtools. the only error i get in the console is this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYkGy.png) and when i click on the only clickable link in the error, i get this [error location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntNjs.png). i have no idea where to start looking to find where the error is being caused

after looking online for reasons of crashes, i couldnt find much, one of the solutions i tried was to see any subscriptions that are unhandled (unsubcribed from) that can cause memory leaks, i looked in the app and i found a few that i have resolved, but that didnt fix the issue

Comment: How did you do your upgrade? Did you go one major version at a time using `ng update`? Having personally run into similar situations, it's usually best to use `ng update` one major version at a time and then run the app each time.

Also, it's worth mentioning that sometime after a major update it's best to get rid of the `.angular` folder and your `node_modules` folder and just do an `npm ci` and then start the app. I have had weird behavior when just trying to run the app after an upgrade.